# Finding unique objects alphabetically

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand how does the SQL works thru the SQLZOO website. And I stucked at the task: List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically. I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT continent, name 
FROM world 
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' 
ORDER BY name
```

But then I found this:

```
SELECT continent, name 
FROM world x 
WHERE name <= ALL(SELECT name FROM world y WHERE x.continent = y.continent)
```

Finding an answer wasn't optional, I've just realized that I don't understand how to solve the task correctly. Because in my code it gives "Europe" two or more times. And at the same time I don't understand why this code works because in my opinion "name <=" don't have any sense. Please help, I just don't get at all how this thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just looking for countries that start with an `A`, such as Albania, Austria, and Andorra.

This code is doing something quite different:

```
SELECT continent, name 
FROM world x 
WHERE name <= ALL (SELECT name FROM world y WHERE x.continent = y.continent);
```

The `WHERE` condition is saying "the name is less than or equal to all the names of the countries on that continent".  The "on that continent" part is where the correlation clause comes in (`x.continent = y.continent`).  The the `<= ALL` does the rest.  Obviously, `<` would not work here, because no country's name is less than itself.

Personally, I wouldn't teach this particular method.  I would rather explain:

```
SELECT continent, name 
FROM world x 
WHERE name = (SELECT MIN(name) FROM world y WHERE x.continent = y.continent);
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT continent, MIN(name)
FROM world
GROUP BY continent;
```

I think both of these express the logic in a simpler way.

Comment: What eans this "MIN(name)" what  can be "minimum" for a text type of data?

Comment: `MIN()` and `MAX()` are perfectly well defined on strings.  Technically, they use something called a "collation" (which you can research).  In practice, it uses alphabetical ordering.

Comment: But why DISTICNT itself don't give the unique names/valuses? It doesn't make any sens to me, I really don't get it.

Comment: @Balloonbear . . . `select distinct` is a clause in SQL that returns unique values across *all* columns/expressions in the `select`.  It does not return distinct values based on only one column.

Comment: The why with my code it returns Europe twice if it goes with DISTINCT in the begining?

Comment: @Balloonbear . . . Because Europe has multiple countries that start with "A".  The `select distinct` applies to both the continent and the country.